# Regresar arreglo de vistas de laravel a ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, listview

Tengo un método que retorna un arreglo de vistas

```
$array = [
    'desktop' => view('results-json'),
    'ipad' => view('results-json-ipad'),
]

return $array;
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que ese ese arreglo se pueda renderizar en la vista si estoy accediendo a él desde un ajax? Algo como esto:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    data: { ... },
    success: function(res){
        $('#element').html(res.desktop)
    }
})
```

De antemano gracias por su ayuda e ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

intenta con esto!

```
$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    data: { ... },
    dataType:json,
    success: function(res){
        $.each( res.desktop, function( key, value ) {
           console.log( key + ": " + value );
       });
    }
})
```

Comment: Además de eso, en el array tuve que poner un cast string para que funcionara 'desktop' => (string) view('results-json'). 
Gracias por tu ayuda.